# Query Optimization with multiple joins on through tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I need to have distinct records for all, right now since most products have multiple keywords, so multiple records are recorded.  This is a mysql query and it needs to be optimized for search because it is rather slow. Any thoughts? I appreciate the help

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `p`.`slug`,
  `p`.`image_code`,
  `p`.`name` AS `products_name`,
  `a`.`name` AS `authors_name`,
  `c`.`name` AS `category_name`,
  `cf`.`name` AS `color_family_name` 
FROM
  `products` AS `p` 
  INNER JOIN
  `categories_products` AS `cp` 
  ON (`p`.`id` = `cp`.`product_id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `categories` AS `c` 
  ON (`cp`.`categories_id` = `c`.`id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `artists_products` AS `ap` 
  ON (`p`.`id` = `ap`.`product_id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `artists` AS `a` 
  ON (`ap`.`artists_id` = `a`.`id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `products_keywords` AS `pk` 
  ON (`p`.`id` = `pk`.`product_id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `keywords` AS `kw` 
  ON (`pk`.`keyword_id` = `kw`.`id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `colors_products` AS `cop` 
  ON (`p`.`id` = `cop`.`product_id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `colors` AS `col` 
  ON (`cop`.`colors_id` = `col`.`id`) 
  INNER JOIN
  `colors_family` AS `cf` 
  ON (
    `col`.`color_family_id` = `cf`.`id`
  ) 
WHERE `p`.`image_code` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `p`.`slug` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `p`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `a`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `c`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `kw`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `col`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `cf`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `col`.`pantone_code` LIKE '%red%' 
  AND `p`.`active` = 1 
LIMIT 60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, since you are using a large number of OR criteria on your query, performance is only going to be so good.  The main area of optimization will be limiting the result sets prior to joining and moving unneeded joins to the WHERE clause. This will allow MySQL to optimize the data it uses to speed up the query.  Since you're not returning data from the keywords table, that's the logical place to begin.  Also, you can pare down the products table early to discard the inactive records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `p`.`slug`,
  `p`.`image_code`,
  `p`.`name` AS `products_name`,
  `a`.`name` AS `authors_name`,
  `c`.`name` AS `category_name`,
  `cf`.`name` AS `color_family_name` 
FROM
  (SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`slug`, `p`.`image_code`, `p`.`name` FROM `products` AS `p` WHERE `p`.`active` = 1) AS `p`
INNER JOIN `artists_products` AS `ap` ON (`p`.`id` = `ap`.`product_id`) 
INNER JOIN `artists` AS `a` ON (`ap`.`artists_id` = `a`.`id`) 

INNER JOIN `categories_products` AS `cp` ON (`p`.`id` = `cp`.`product_id`) 
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON (`cp`.`categories_id` = `c`.`id`) 

INNER JOIN `colors_products` AS `cop` ON (`p`.`id` = `cop`.`product_id`) 
INNER JOIN `colors` AS `col` ON (`cop`.`colors_id` = `col`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `colors_family` AS `cf` ON (`col`.`color_family_id` = `cf`.`id`) 

WHERE `p`.`image_code` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `p`.`slug` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `p`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `a`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `c`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `p`.`id`. IN (SELECT `pk`.`product_id` FROM `products_keywords` INNER JOIN `keywords` AS `kw` ON (`pk`.`keyword_id` = `kw`.`id`) WHERE `kw`.`name` LIKE '%red%')
  OR `col`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `cf`.`name` LIKE '%red%' 
  OR `col`.`pantone_code` LIKE '%red%'
LIMIT 60
```

Comment: is there an alternative to using so many OR's on a search, besides match against, since this isnt a fulltext search..which im thinking about modifying it to

Comment: Ideally, I'd turn each of the join sections into a subquery, but since you're actually using that data, it wouldn't be useful. Have you checked to see that you're indexing the fields you're querying on? That's a good low hanging fruit for complex searches like this.

Comment: ya, that will be setup when I get the production DB setup.  Right now, im working on a dev server so its substantially slower.  But 1/4 to 1/2 a second for each is not good